# Implement a "Remember me" CheckBox in windows application?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, desktop-application, .net-3.5, remember-me

Hello I am creating a Windows application (WPF) that is going to be running in few stations accessing 1 database.

I already implemented a login form with a login system thru `My.User.CurrentPrincipal`.
Now, I want to implement a "Remember me on this computer" check box in the login form, where should I store the value?

Should it be a cookie? a .settings value? or what good other suggestion do you have.

**Update**
Also what data (i.e. what value) shoud I store, I want it to be secure, that users should not be able to copy the values etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you want a TTL (time to live) for the "remember me" functionality?  Should the program ask them to re-enter user name and password after a predetermined amount of time?

Scenario - User logs in with Remember Me set to true and a TTL of 2 days.  They can open and close app without being prompted to log in for that time period, but, after that, they will be prompted to log in again.

Comment: Putting together an answer/ code sample that I think will work for you.

Comment: But this is not the problem since I if there is going to be a sliding ttl, it's going to be preset in the application settings.
So I will store the expirration (or creation) date along with the username to automatically login to.
The question was what resource to use (i.e. registry etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would probably want to store in the registry and i dont think u have cookies in desktop apps.

Comment: You can also use the local application data directory.

Comment: 1) What values should I store?
2) Consider putting it in your question body.

Comment: Look up registry manipulation in ur respective language in google and you will find tonnes of examples. As for what values , i guess you can encrypt and store the username and password.